# How to chage content-type in interceptor in angular 6?

Tags: angular6, angular-http-interceptors

Some services need to have token,some have different Content-Type.how should I manage them in an Interceptor file?

Answer (score 5):

You can get or set all request headers on your interceptor function. The following code reveals headers proprty for handling this changes:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (request.headers.has('Content-Type'))
       contentType = request.headers.get('Content-Type');

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`,
        'Content-Type': (contentType != 'application/json' ? 'application/text' :  contentType)
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Comment: if (request.headers.has('Content-Type')) condition is always false.I set header in service in This way : 
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers
    };
return this.http.post(this.tokenUrl, body, httpOptions)

Comment: You should set the request header on the specified HTTP method (e.g. `HttpClient.Get<T>(url, options)` ). This is an example of this usage: 

`return this.http.get<T>(this.path, {
            params: this.getHttpParams(params),
            responseType: type,
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
        })`

Comment: If you don't set your request content-type on the request-header, you can set it on your HTTP interceptor.

Comment: Check your developer network log and watch for the request. On the correct header definition, you will see `content-type` on developer console for your request. Otherwise check your request header definition again. Good Luck!